# Pass Values from View to Controller MVC4.0 c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, onclick, submit

I am new to MVC and I have view for search record as below

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchRecord", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table class="table table-striped">                   
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("txtCallerId",  Model.callerNo, new { placeholder = "Caller Number", @class = "form-control" })

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="divlstCampaigns">
                                <select id="lstCampaigns" name="lstCampaigns[]" multiple="multiple">
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.cmpList)
                                    {
                                        <option value='@item.campaignName'>@item.campaignName</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bg-info" value="Submit">Search</button>  </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
```

and controller

```
    public ActionResult SearchRecord()
    {
        string userName = TempData["user"] as string;
        instance = TempData["instance"] as IInstance;
       ......
        lstSearchCriteria objSearc = new lstSearchCriteria();
        objSearc.agentList = agentList;
        objSearc.cmpList = campaignList;

        return View(objSearc);
    }      
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchRecord(lstSearchCriteria form)
    {
        List<lstCampaign> lstCmp = form.cmpList;//NULL Value here
        string callerNo = form.callerNo;//NULL Value here

        return View();
    }
```

My Model is :

```
  public class lstSearchCriteria
  {
    public List<lstCampaign> cmpList { get; set; }     
    public string callerNo { get; set; }
    // ......
  }
```

What I expect is when I click on the submit or Search button. Values from text box & drop-down boxes should be visible in the controller. But I am getting all null values.

Comment: Could you pls give us your  `lstCampaign` model?

Comment: public class lstCampaign
    {
        public string campaignName { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

**View:**

```
<select id="cmpList" name="cmpList" multiple="multiple">
```

**lstSearchCriteria**:

```
public string[] cmpList { get; set; }
```

[This](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support) link is very helpful for you.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect for dropdown which requires [] to append in name to get values at server side.  Any help would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Razor controls like this in the html. And Remember List must have data in it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchRecord", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table class="table table-striped">                   
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.callerNo , new { placeholder = "Caller Number", @class = "form-control" })

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="divlstCampaigns">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.cmpList,'Select', new {  @class = "form-control" } )
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bg-info" value="Submit">Search</button>  </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
```

Also try to replace List to SelectList type.

Comment: Thanks ! With this I am getting value for callerNo. But for Dropdownlist it shows "Too many characters in character literal" at ,'Select'  Also I am using MVC 4.0. Not sure if SelectList type will work, Would be great if you can give sample.

Comment: Any update I tried with selectList as well but no luck.